# Multiple LoginInfos with silhouette (play 2.3, reactivemongo)

Tags: authentication, playframework-2.3, reactivemongo

Currently I build an application which uses silhouette for authentication. Every user should be able to authenticate via different providers.

Actually I cant figure out how to implement "silhouette" since the Identity trait only includes a single LoginInfo instead of a Sequence of LoginInfo. Is there any way around it or does someone know how to implement this or even better knows an example project which implemented it that way?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create a separate case class for User. Lets call it *DBUser*.

This case class will contain a field with a list of *LoginInfo*s. Once you know which *LoginInfo* you should use in *UserService*, you will need to cast *DBUser* into *User* (the one that extends Identity) with the corresponding *LoginInfo*.